# Simplicity is elegance? or elegant?

Tags: grammar, nouns, adjectives

As the title asks, which is grammatically correct? Simplicity is elegance? Or simplicity is elegant? If both are correct,in which cases they are correct?

Comment: Hi @Morison  can you please explain why you need this information and tell us what research you have done so far? In the first sentence you are saying that the word 'simplicity' equals or has the same meaning as the word 'elegance'. The second sentence means that a characteristic of simplicity is that it is elegant, in the same way that you would say that 'the sun is hot'. You may find it useful to check the definitions of words in dictionaries, to make sure you understand their meaning. Best wishes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grammar is fine in both but if the second definition of the words [elegant](https://www.google.com/search?q=elegant%20definition)/[elegance](https://www.google.com/search?q=elegance%20definition), *"pleasingly ingenious and simple"*, are meant (and the word they are being equated to strongly suggests they are) then both are factually wrong: simplicity is not necessarily ingenious (and if it were it would be a tautology).

To say "the noun is noun" is to say they are equivalent.
To say "the noun is adjective" is to describe the noun: a lot less specific and absolute.

A hill could be described as mountainous but it is not a mountain.

Therefore, I suggest you use "simplicity is elegant". It is less factually incorrect.

If the first definition of [elegant](https://www.google.com/search?q=elegant%20definition)/[elegance](https://www.google.com/search?q=elegance%20definition), *"graceful and stylish"*, are meant then either would be fine. Those concepts are far too vague and subjective for the sentence to be considered wrong. Nevertheless, the more vague describing with adjective than equating to noun might still be preferable here too for the same reason.

Comment: @Davor The use of the word 'a' is an important difference - it makes the comparison to the larger set. Elegance is **a** simplicity would be correct. Simplicity is not an elegance as fruit is not an apple.

Answer (score 5):

They mean different things.  "Simplicity is elegant" means that the simple is stylish.  "Simplicity is elegance" means that simple design and stylishness are equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. Simplicity is elegance.
> 2. Simplicity  is elegant.

The first sentence here is an example of what is known as the *EQUATIVE* or *SPECIFYING* use of the verb *BE*. It shows that a particular entity is also another type of entity. So in the sentence:

- Bob is a man.

... the equative use of *BE* indicates that the entity *Bob* is also an example of *a man*.

The second sentence illustrates the use of *ASCRIPTIVE BE*. In sentences like this where *BE* is followed by an adjective, the adjective usually tells us about some quality of the entity:

- Bob is tall.

In the sentence above the adjective *tall* describes a property of Bob.

So in the first sentence simplicity is specified as a type of elegance. In the second the word *elegant* tells us a property of simplicity. They are both grammatically correct, but the meanings are slightly different.